# Why float element does not overlap on h3 element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My observation is, float elements overlap on its previous elements, but in the below code, `div` element did not over lap `body` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>All selector</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            h3{
                margin: 0;
                heigth: 10px;
            }
            div, span, p{
                width: 80px;
                height: 40px;
                float: left;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px;
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>DIV</div>
        <span>SPAN</span>
        <p>P<button>BUTTON</button></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var elementCount = $('*').css("border", "3px solid red").length;
            $('body').prepend("<h3>" + elementCount + " elements found</h3>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Actual output is:

### [image]

As per my understanding on `float:left`,

Expected output is,

[image]
Why 3 float elements `div`, `span` & `p` are not overlapping on `body` element?

Comment: @JaromandaX `clear:left;` is to make `div`, `span` & `p` does not have any element on its left.

Comment: In addition to down vote, please explain the reason. This would help me, correct myself.

Comment: you are getting confused with positioning, you should look up the difference between relative and absolute and how this is relevent to floats.
In all honesty you shouldnt be using floats to position, you should be using flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating element is shown floating against the content that follows it. There is no content after the div / span / p tags. Note: you are prepending the h3 tag to body. Try appending and see what output you get.